# Can I use a magnet to make a hinged mirror stick to the wall?

Tags: mounting, mirror

After installing my Ikea mirror which can open like a door (in order to install small hooks on the wall behind it and hang keys and stuff), I realize it touches the wall only if I apply pressure on it, otherwise there's a 1 centimeter gap.

I was thinking about installing a small magnet on the wall at half height of the mirror, then a small metal sheet glued on the mirror at the same height so that the mirror is attracted by the magnet.

Ideally the magnet on the wall would be a simple screw whose head is a magnet! Is there such a thing?

Otherwise, what do you suggest?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The magnet idea sounds like a practical solution. You even have some good ideas in the answers so far. Do however make a trial experiment to check if the magnet you select has the necessary holding power before you struggle through the formal mounting of said magnet. Some of these things are not particularly strong and it would be a big disappointment to get it all mounted up only to find it does not work.

Comment: Also be aware that most magnetic catches are strong in holding power only if the magnet and the metal catch plate come onto complete flat contact with each other. If the catch plate is at an angle to the magnet surface only a fraction of the holding power will be achieved. Note that some magnetic cabinet catches have one part made so that it has some free play in its mechanism so that the two parts can self align when they come into contact.

Comment: I know this is old, but what kind of hinge are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why, of course! You're looking for a "magnetic catch".
Just you should possibly install it the other way around - a metal plate on the wall, and the catch screwed on the mirror.

**Images added:**

1. Magnet mounted as plug in the cabinet with large head screw contact
2. Magnet in cup washer and mating contact washer mounted with screws
3. Thin magnet to metal plate

[image][image][image]